# Some tags not recognized in expanded directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to avoid some repeated HTML, but am having trouble getting my directive to work completely. In a simplified version of my code, the idea is to expand something like:

```
<mydir ng-model="x"></mydir>
```

to something like:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': myform.myfield.$invalid}">
    <input name="myfield" ng-model="x" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/">
</div>
```

However, the ng-class is completely ignored. ng-model and ng-pattern seem to be working fine. My directive:

```
.directive('mydir', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 100,
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            var node = '<div ng-class=' +
                '"{\'has-error\': myform.myfield2.$invalid}">' +
                '<input name="myfield2" ng-model="' + attrs['ngModel'] +
                '" ng-pattern="/^\\d+$/"></div>';
            var e = angular.element(node);
            $compile(e.contents());
            element.replaceWith(e);
        }
    };
}
```

In the [running code](http://jsfiddle.net/Davepar/GtLuc/) you can see how the first input field correctly turns red with an invalid entry like "ab", but the second input does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the inner HTML of the directive rather than replacing it entirely...

```
compile: function (element, attrs) {
    var node = '<div ng-class=' +
        '"{\'has-error\': myform.myfield2.$invalid}">' +
        '<input name="myfield2" ng-model="' + attrs['ngModel'] +
        '" ng-pattern="/^\\d+$/"></div>';

    element.html(node);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5eLxw/

Comment: Can you also mention what went wrong, so that it helps others too.

Comment: Tinkering around this morning, I discovered that I can also fix it by wrapping the replacement html in another <div>. I suspect that Angular has already scanned the node being processed, so it doesn't find the directives that I added, e.g. the ng-class.